# Align the plot to the right to keep all plot in the extent when using the setZoom function from the shinyEffects package

Tags: r, shiny

In the following example, I used the `setZoom` function from the `shinyEffects` to zoom the plot. It works nicely. However, is it possible to align the plot to the right to keep all plot in the extent? Right now the legend, which is on the right, could not be displayed because it is outside the extent of the browser. It would be great if I can keep the legend on the right and expand the plot to the left when zoom to the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyEffects)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "slide", label = "Select a number to filter the depth",
                  min = 40, max = 80, value = 60)
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      br(),
      br(),
      br(),
     plotOutput("diamond_p"),
     setZoom(id = "diamond_p", scale = 1.5)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$diamond_p <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(diamonds %>% filter(depth >= input$slide), aes(x = carat, y = price,
                                                               color = cut)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_color_viridis_d() +
      theme_classic()
    return(p)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do we stick with the package. Let's have some fun with CSS. Add the following CSS to your app and it works even better. You can customize a lot of more things:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput(inputId = "slide", label = "Select a number to filter the depth",
                        min = 40, max = 80, value = 60)
        ),
        mainPanel = mainPanel(
            plotOutput("diamond_p"),
            tags$style(
            '
            #diamond_p{
                transition: all 0.2s;
            }
            #diamond_p:hover{
                transform: translateX(-25%) translateY(25%) scale(1.5);
                z-index: 999;
                position: relative;
            }            
            '
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$diamond_p <- renderPlot({
        p <- ggplot(diamonds %>% filter(depth >= input$slide), aes(x = carat, y = price,
                                                                   color = cut)) +
            geom_point() +
            scale_color_viridis_d() +
            theme_classic()
        return(p)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

1. specify your animation time in `transition`
2. Play around with `translateX` and `translateY` to adjust the position
3. Use `scale` to change zoom level.
4. No need of `br()`
5. After zoom, some other element may be on top of the image, increase `z-index` until they no longer cover the plot. Delete this and see what happens.

Updates: I just check the `{shinyEffects}` source code. It is doing very similar CSS tricks but only with limited things you can change.

Comment: Wonderful. You are right. It works even better. Thanks.